# Explicit formula for entropy

Tags: thermodynamics

Helle everyone, I have a question regarding the exact definition of entropy.

When you look up te derivation (proof) of the Clausius-inequality, for example on wikipedia, the formula $$ d S = \frac{\delta Q}{T} $$ is used, without specifying the path to be reversible or not.

However, some definitions state that de change is entropy can only be calculated if the path taken is reversible i.e. $$ d S = \frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T} $$

I am really struggling with this, so where am I wrong in my thinking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I personally think that the proof on the wiki page is just not a very good one. It is not very careful with points like this (which are very important for Clausius theroem). Not to mention that it starts with the statement $dS \ge 0$, when one of the key applications of Clausius inequality is to derive the increase in entropy for the Kelvin or Clausius statements of the second law.

Comment: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem) to wiki page in question